# How to authenticate via MVC to allow SPA wep api auth

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am struggling to log in with my MVC ASP.NET core application which also uses web api (all asp.net core).

The user logs in with the MVC application - this works fine.

The issue is, when they call a web API, `User` (as in `User.Identity`) is always null

The code I'm using to authenticate is

```
private static async Task Create(string value, string cookieName, Controller controller)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    { 
        new Claim(cookieName, value),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
    };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
            );

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true,
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        await controller.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);
}
```

When I then call an end point in Web API, `User` is always null.

If I navigate to another MVC Controller, then `User` has a value.

I am guessing the issue is because I'm logging in (creating cookie) using `controller` and that's a different type of controller to the one `web api` uses

I'm not sure what to do - Do I need to some how make the cookie persist over both MVC and WebApi end points?

Comment: If you want to communicate with your API from the frontend so you need token and for creating token you can use JWT.

Comment: Cookie authentication only work for Asp.Net core pages and controllers.